# Displaying amount of "filled" rows in group header WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, converters

I have a certain amount of rows in my ViewModel observablecollection that are being grouped and displayed in a datagrid.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ColViewSource" Source="{Binding Collection}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Cat"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

My rows contain a textfield and a threestate checkbox that needs to be true or indeterminate state for the row to be considered "filled" (default false). I would like to display the amount of "filled" rows in my groupheader out of total items in group. For example if I have a group with 5 items and the user ticked 2 of the checkboxes I would like to see 2 out of 5 or 2 / 5 in group header. I can manage to get the name and itemcount without a problem to display in groupheader but Im stuck on displaying the amount of filled rows. Here is how I would like my group header to look.

```
<Expander.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        implement this-->
        <TextBlock Text = amount of items currently filled.
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander.Header>
```

I have implemented propertychanged for both my collection and items. Im guessing it would require some sort of converter , can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think  1st, you need to data binding with isChecked property of checkbox to know how many checkbox were checked. 2nd, then you can add some code in get property of numOfFilledItems field, in ViewModel to count it.

Comment: Did you try using an _IValueConverter_?

Comment: How is your data object type that contains the Cat property defined?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx), Your group style must look like this in Xaml:

```
 <local:PercentageConverterx:Key="percentageConverter" />
//...
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource percentageConverter} }"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
       </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

in which

```
public class PercentageConverter: IValueConverter
{ 
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CollectionViewGroup cvg = value as CollectionViewGroup;
        int count = 0;
        int check = 0;
        foreach (Item t in cvg.Items)
        {
            count++;
            if (t.IsCheck== true)
                check++;
        }
        return (check / (double)count).ToString("0.00") + "%";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Note that I assumed *CollectionViewSource.Source* property is set to a *ObservableCollection* in which Item is like this:

```
public class Item
{
     public string Name {get; set; }
     public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

which is bound to the threestate *CheckBox*.

Comment: Use a similar converter to get the Count too.